# Classify Pointcloud using thematic layer with lidR

Tags: r, classification, lidr, point-cloud

I want to use lidR to classify points within a point cloud using a few thematic shapefiles. This includes buildings, vegetation and cars. For this I use the `classify_poi` function, which works for buildings and vegetation, because there are already classes like `LASBUILDING`  and
`LASHIGHVEGETATION` . For the class cars, however, there is no prefabricated class (e.g. `LASCAR` ).

How can I create my own class, or do I have to switch to other class descriptions?

```
building = sf::st_read("buildings_25832.shp", quiet = TRUE)
veg = sf::st_read("veg_25832.shp", quiet = TRUE)
car = sf::st_read("car_25832.shp", quiet = TRUE)

las_class = classify_poi(las, LASBUILDING, roi = building, inverse = FALSE)
las_class = classify_poi(las_class, LASHIGHVEGETATION, roi = veg, inverse = FALSE)
las_class = classify_poi(las_class, ???, roi = car, inverse = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LASfile format is based on [public specifications](https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/LAS_1_4_r15.pdf). The specs defines some class and their associated code (page 19 and 30) but `car` is not part of the standard. There is no official number for this classification.

The specifications describes how to create and document your own classes but `lidR` does not offer tools for that. The simplest option is to select the number of your choice and use this number as code. Let assume you chose 21 for `car`. Be careful:

- 21 corresponds to nothing official and you did not write the proper information in the header to document that 21 corresponds to `car` so you and only you can know it that 21 = car.
- For LAS format < 1.4 the classification is a 5 bits fields so you are limited to 32 values and 0-12 are reserved. The other values are not supposed to be user-defined but nothing prevent you of assigning the value 21 to a point. For LAS 1.4 the classification is a 8 bits fields with 64-255 that are user definable.

```r
las_class = classify_poi(las_class, 21L, roi = car, inverse = FALSE)
```